# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table' when obtaining data from a database

Tags: c#

I have created a method which is retrieving data from a local database and displaying it in a list box.

```
        private void getOwned()
    {
        string connection = "server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;database=<default>;Integrated Security=SSPI";
        string sql = @"select * from Table";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Table");
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Table"];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                lst_information.DataSource = row[col];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

when I run the code there is an error which is appearing "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'" I was just wondering why this error is occurring. Thanks for any help which you can provide.

Comment: Table is a keyword in sql

Comment: Try `string sql = @"select * from [Table]";`

Comment: you cannot use it like this..try like this: select * from [Table]

Comment: how to highlight code in comments?? @SriramSakthivel

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: put it around backquotes ( ` )

Comment: @EhsanSajjad [You've to wrap it inside backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87356/how-to-highlight-comments-in-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table` is a [reserved keyword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in `TSQL`, you need to put *square brackets* around it:

```
 string sql = @"select * from [Table]";
```